# highlight-regexp(s) with looping over an alist

Tags: quote

Although these two expressions seems to be equivalent (both works):

```el
;; 1
(highlight-regexp "foo" "hi-green")

;; 2
(highlight-regexp "foo" 'hi-green)
```

Only the first one of the following loops works appropriately:

```el
;; 1
(defun my-highlights ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((ALIST  '(("foo" . "hi-green")
                   ("bar" . "hi-yellow"))))
    (dolist (COUPLE LIST)
      (let* ((REGEXP (car COUPLE))
             (HI_FACE (cdr COUPLE)))
        (highlight-regexp REGEXP HI_FACE)))))

;; 2
(defun my-highlights ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((ALIST  '(("foo" . 'hi-green)
                   ("bar" . 'hi-yellow))))
    (dolist (COUPLE LIST)
      (let* ((REGEXP (car COUPLE))
             (HI_FACE (cdr COUPLE)))
        (highlight-regexp REGEXP HI_FACE)))))
```

In the second case the cdr of the cons cell is ignored. Why? (I'd like to use the form `("foo" . face)`.)

Comment: Remove the quote from the cdr in the second version’s alist. Does it work?

Comment: @Dan It works. Thank you. I was sure I tried to do it. Please, post you comment as an answer so that I can accept it and close this issue.